# Netty Parallel Handler Processing

Tags: parallel-processing, netty, blocking

Following recommendations elsewhere I am attempting to parallelize my final inbound handler in a Netty pipeline as such

```
public final class EchoServer {
    private EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    private UnorderedThreadPoolEventExecutor workers = new UnorderedThreadPoolEventExecutor(10);

    public void start(int port) throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
            b.group(group).channel(NioDatagramChannel.class).option(ChannelOption.SO_BROADCAST, true)
                    .handler(new ChannelInitializer<NioDatagramChannel>() {
                        @Override
                        protected void initChannel(NioDatagramChannel channel) throws Exception {
                            channel.pipeline().addLast(workers, new SimpleChannelInboundHandler<DatagramPacket>() {
                                @Override
                                public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, DatagramPacket packet) throws Exception {
                                    System.err.println(packet);
                                    // Simulated database delay that I have to wait to occur before repsonding
                                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                                    ctx.write(new DatagramPacket(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("goodbye", StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1), packet.sender()));
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
                                    ctx.flush();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
                                    cause.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });

            b.bind(port).sync().channel().closeFuture().await();
        } finally {
            group.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        group.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}
```

I have ten clients that connect concurrently, as a test, and I am measuring execution time for handling all the requests. As expected with the 1 second delay and sequential execution it takes just over 10 seconds. I am trying to get execution down to somewhere sub 2 seconds to prove parallel handling.

From what I understand adding the handler to the pipeline with an explicitly assigned executor is supposed to parallelize that handlers work across the thread in the executor.

Instead of seeing a increase in performance, what I am finding is that my client is not receiving the responses when I add the parallel processing. The thread sleep is there to simulate the potential time it will take to write the incoming data to a database. Am I doing something obviously wrong here?

Comment: Apparently this is a shortcoming in Netty with regards to UDP channels. https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/1706

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around the apparently lack of Netty support for doing final end UDP processing in parallel using standard java concurrency mechanisms.

```
public final class EchoServer {
    private EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    private ExecutorService executors = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    public void start(int port) throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
            b.group(group).channel(NioDatagramChannel.class).handler(new ChannelInitializer<NioDatagramChannel>() {
                @Override
                protected void initChannel(NioDatagramChannel channel) throws Exception {
                    channel.pipeline().addLast(new SimpleChannelInboundHandler<DatagramPacket>() {
                        @Override
                        public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, DatagramPacket packet) throws Exception {
                            CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                                System.err.println(packet);
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                ctx.writeAndFlush(new DatagramPacket(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("goodbye", StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1),
                                        packet.sender()));
                            }, executors);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
                            ctx.flush();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
                            cause.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            b.bind(port).sync().channel().closeFuture().await(); 
        } finally {
            group.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        group.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please explain one thing to me about Netty: please correct me if I'm wrong. So there is an event loop (i.e. demultiplexer) waiting for requests, and whenever the request comes in, the demultiplexer dispatches it to the handler pipeline. My question is, does event loop block waiting for the message to pass though all inbound and outbound handlers? or it just dispatches and proceeds?

Comment: Unsure. Been a while since I read the book.